# What does this jQuery code with square brackets and a caret mean?

Tags: jquery

What does this jQuery code mean?

```
$('tr[id^="message"]')
```

Comment: -1 as it is almost exact sample on selectors page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means - select all `tr` elements which `id` attribute starts with `message` string

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 7):

`[]` refers to an element's attribute(s) (id being one) and `id^` is a wildcard which means the id must start with "message".

Answer (score 5):

It means a table row who has an id that starts with "message":

```
$('tr // a table row
[id //having an id 
^="message"]') // starting with 'message'
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/